# persist previous state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays of object which they depend on each other.

```
const types = [{
  id:1,
  name: 'male'
},{
  id:2,
  name: 'female'
}]

const voices = [{
  value: 20
},{
  value: 40
},{
  value: 60
},{
  value: 80
},{
  value: 100
}]
```

Voices depend on types. I want to control the state where if user selected male type, a new list will be shown to the user, and user can check the checkboxes. Once user clicked on another type, for example, female, a new list of types with uncheck checkboxes will be shown. The challenge is when the user clicked back to male, how to keep the state of previously selected type (eg. male) so it will persist?

**DEMO https://codesandbox.io/s/4w07v2opn9**

Comment: You demo sandbox is no different from the default sandbox

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri wasted my effort of 10 min. Now my code is gone!

Comment: What did I do with your sandbox, I can't make any change to your sandbox, if I try to do it, it will fork your original sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Keep voicesMale and voicesFemale separately, and decide which ones to set in handleChange, based on the selected type value

Comment: if I have 100 type, I have 100 set of voices?

Comment: I don't see any other way. It is an array, the headache is on the poor CPU, not on you :)